# How to get current route from outside in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, parameters

Is it possible to get the current route from an outside component?

Basically, I have a Page title component that would only display the current page title. Can't seem to figure out how to access the routes from an outside component?

Edit: 
**App.jsx**

`<div style={styles.container}>
                <Sidebar style={styles.sidebar} links={sidebarLinks}/>
                <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <Header style={styles.header}/>
                    <div style={styles.content}>
                  <PageTitle style={styles.pageTitle} /> //Want current route here
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    <Footer style={styles.footer}/>
                </div>
            </div>`

**Routes**

```
    const routes =  (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="containers" component={Containers} />
    <Route path="discover" component={Discover} />
    <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
    <Route path="profiles" component={Profiles} />
</Route>
);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but take a look at this maybe? https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: @zackify See edit please. Basically, I have not added a route to the page title component because it's just page title across all pages.

Comment: Ah, I see. A much better way to do this would be to put the `<PageTitle />` component on the specific pages. Another way, but not as good: React router will inject the routes object to your top level component, you *could* do something like `routes[routes.length -1]` to get the last route that matches I believe.

Comment: @zackify What do you mean when you said put <PageTitle /> component on specific pages? You mean on the routes? Can you provide me the example?

Comment: On `Containers`, `Discover`, etc. Put the page title on each of these components.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking. Maybe you can use the `window.location` API:

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
window.location.pathname
```